# React Modal NPM: Trying to use React Modal but getting errors with installation

Tags: meteor, reactjs, modal-dialog, npm

I am using React with Meteor.
I have decided to use React Modal https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment' from '/Users/bliss/Coder/ReactMeteor/vedicjoy-react/packages/npm-container/.npm/package/node_modules/react-modal/lib/components'
```

The steps I took where:
1.) In my package.json file I added `"react-modal": "0.5.0"`

2.) In the client.browserify.js I added `Modal = require('react-modal');`

Then after I got the error I even tried adding this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/exenv
to the package.son file ...but that did not make the error go away.

I am using MeteorJS Framework with React.

What can I do to make `react-modal` work inside my project?

Comment: Did you use  `npm install --save react-modal`, so that it was added to your node_modules folder?  It looks like you just added it to the package.json file, and didn't actually install it.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using React 0.14 in your Browserify packages. Facebook removed ExecutionEnvironment from this version of React, the [react-modal devs are aware of this](https://github.com/rackt/react-modal/pull/79#issue-111035986), and it has been solved in the new release (which apparently comes out sometime this afternoon).

#### Quick fix.

Here's a quick fix until that happens ([source](https://gist.github.com/inuscript/0554364279249287962c)):

```
$ npm i -D fbjs
```

Then in `yourproject/packages/npm-container/.npm/package/node_modules/react-modal/lib/components/Modal.js` replace `'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment'` with `'fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment'`

**Edit:** it's not as easy as I thought. Apparently components of different React releases aren't compatible with eachother. :-(. Will report back later.

Comment: Actually I'm not using React 0.14....On my browser if I type React.version I get React.version "0.13.3"....

Comment: I think the version of the package that is being browserified will be bundled with the 0.14 version of React, thus the issue.